# Warning: Displayed transactions may not be correct!

Tags: wallet, network

After several weeks of not updating my QT wallet I get the message "Warning: Displayed transactions may not be correct! You may need to upgrade, or other nodes may need to upgrade."  I tried uninstalling bitcoin QT and installing the latest version but that didn't do anything.  I don't know much about bitcoin wallets so a detailed explanation of how to fix this would be great! thanks

Comment: The latest version as of this writing is 0.8.6; are you certain that is the version you installed?

Comment: I'm absolutely positive.